# Exercise 5, Section 1.2 of Hungerford’s Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing, equivalence-relations

> Let $S$ be a non empty subset of a group $G$ and define a relation on $G$ by $a\sim b$ if and only if $ab^{-1}\in S$. Show that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation if and only if $S$ is a subgroup of $G$.

**My attempt:** Let $\emptyset \neq S\subseteq G$ and $\sim =\{(a,b)\in G\times G\mid ab^{-1}\in S\}$. $(\Rightarrow)$ Supppose $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $G$. Let $a,b\in S$. Since $ae^{-1}=a\in S$ and $be^{-1}=b\in S$, we have $(a,e),(b,e)\in \sim$. By symmetry, we have $(e,b)\in \sim$. By transitivity, $(a,b)\in \sim$. That is $ab^{-1}\in S$. Thus $S\neq \emptyset$ and $ab^{-1}\in S$ for all $a,b\in S$. Hence $S\leq G$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Suppose $S\leq G$. Since $gg^{-1}=e\in S$, we have $(g,g)\in \sim$, $\forall g\in G$. So $\sim$ is reflexive. Let $(a,b)\in \sim$. Then $ab^{-1}\in S$. So $(ab^{-1})^{-1}=(b^{-1})^{-1}a^{-1}=ba^{-1}\in S$. Thus $(b,a)\in \sim$ and $\sim$ is symmetric. Let $(a,b)\in \sim$ and $(b,c)\in \sim$. Then $ab^{-1}\in S$ and $bc^{-1}\in S$. So $(ab^{-1})(bc^{-1})=ac^{-1}\in S$. Thus $(a,c)\in \sim$ and $\sim$ is transitive. Hence $\sim$ is an equivalence relation. **Is my proof correct?**

Comment: I don't understand $\in \sim$, because $\sim$ is not a set, or should not be a set. It is $a\sim b$. So $\sim=$ and $\in \sim$ do not look good.

Comment: "symmetric" and "transitive" are adjectives. The corresponding nouns are "symmetry" and "transitivity". Objects should be nouns, so "by transitive" and "by symmetric" are ungrammatical.

Comment: @DietrichBurde My source (lecture notes by Richard Earl) use $\sim$ as set. It perhaps is abuse of notation.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thanks for the correction and edit.

Comment: You should clean up the rest.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin After writing hundreds of this format of question, you'd think they'd have mastered formatting by now.  I intended to link to a SEDE query to explain but I'm not sure it would go over well.

Comment: Each relation on $G$ is a subset of $G\times G$, @DietrichBurde.

Comment: @Shaun I know. Still, $\sim =$, or $\in\sim$ just doesn't look nice.